# Using getseconds() to control rotation of clock images (not animation)

Tags: javascript

I have graphics of a watch, the hour, minute and second hands.  I want to use real-time clock data to control rotation of the images.

I can get all the code components to work separately and can rotate a single image of the second hand.  But when I add the JS and CSS to display and rotate all the images, it displays correctly, but nothing rotates.

```
<script>
function everySecond() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var h = currentTime.getHours();
    var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var s = currentTime.getSeconds();
    if(h == 24){
        h = 0;
    }
    if(h > 12){
       h = h - 12;
    }
    var hp = h * 360 / 12;
    var mp = m * 360 / 60;
    var sp = s * 360 /60;
    $("#seconds").css({
       'transform': 'rotate(' + sp + 'deg)'
    });
    $("#minutes").css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + mp + 'deg)'
    });
    $("#hours").css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + hp + 'deg)'
    });
}
setInterval(everySecond, 1000);
</script>
<style>
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%; 
    margin:-200px 0 0 -200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<div>
    <img class="image" 
src="C:\Users\name\Desktop\Watch\watchhandcompass.gif">
    <img id="hours" class="image"  
src="C:\Users\name\Desktop\Watch\hourhandcompass.gif">
    <img id="minutes" class="image"  
src="C:\Users\name\Desktop\Watch\minutehandcompass.gif">
    <img id="seconds" class="image"  
src="C:\Users\name\Desktop\Watch\secondhandcompass.gif">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Working fine for me, do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Ahh, of course...  testclock2.html:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at everySecond    ... can you suggest a fix?

Comment: The lines beginning with `$` are using jQuery. You need to include jQuery or rewrite those lines to not rely on jQuery (let me know if you need help with that).

Comment: Your code is is working, see https://jsfiddle.net/9ad3twsz/1. Your are missing jQuery reference (see jsfiddle) and your code sample also misses opening `head` tag.

Comment: Thanks all.  I added the jquery and it works great!